# Find all real values of 'a' for which all the function roots are integers.

Tags: quadratics

Find all real values of 'a' for which all the function roots are integers.
$$ f(x) = ax^{2} + (a+1)x + a-1$$

I was thinking about Vieta's formula so:
$$
\\xy = 1 - \frac{1}{a}
\\x + y = -1 - \frac{1}{a} 
\\xy ∈ \Bbb Z 
\\x+y ∈ \Bbb Z.
\\a ∈ \Bbb R
$$

After all of that my answer is $$ a = 0, a = 1 $$

But I'm not sure, how should I prove that those are the only options?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $xy$ is an integer. So $\frac{1}{a}$ must be an integer (note that your case of $a = 0$ results in a linear function, which we have to consider separately). This gives us only 2 cases to work with in the quadratic case; you can verify both by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a\ne 0$.

Sum $S $ of roots is then integer.

$$S=-\frac{a+1}{a}=-1-\frac {1}{a} \in \Bbb Z$$

$\implies  a=1$ or $a=-1$.

for $a=1$, roots are $0,-2$

for $a=-1$ , no root.

If $a=0$, the root is $x=1$.

Finally, $$a\in\{0,1\} $$

Answer (score 0):

a = 1, 0 ,  - 1/7

if c and b be the roots, then
c + b = - 1 - 1/a  and  cb = 1 - 1/a

so,
c + b + 1 = cb - 1
or, ( c - 1 ) ( b - 1 ) = 3 which is 1 x 3 or - 1 x - 3 (commuting will yield the same pair).